# Not redirecting to the component passed in HOC when login success react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga

I'm stuck with form day since past two days. 
When I use localhost:3000/app , app is passed as component to HOC so we see the login page then on success see the dash board but I don't understand when succesfull after success it fails with 
 **err: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops**
Please do lemme know I'm doing it the right way?

index.js // are the routes written the right way?

```
           <Provider store={store}>
                     <Switch>                                                  
                          <Route path="/" component={signIn}/>                                        
                          <Route handler={requireAuth(App)} name="App"/>
                     </Switch>  
               </Provider>
```

Sigin.js

```
                  const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
                    console.log("msp",state)
                    return{
                    isLoggedIn:state.signInReducer.isLoggedIn 
                    }
                  }

                  const mapDispatchToProps={
                    doLoginAction:doLoginAction
                  }

                  class SignInMain extends React.Component {
                    constructor(props){
                      super(props)
                      this.state={
                        userDetails:'',
                        errMsg:false
                      }
                    }

                    componentDidMount(){                    
                      if(this.props.isLoggedIn)
                      this.props.history.push('/app')                          
                    }                      

                    handleInput=(name,val)=>{                          
                      this.setState((prevState)=>{
                        {  const userDetails=prevState.userDetails
                          return{userDetails:{...userDetails,[name]:val}}
                        }
                      })                          
                    }

                    handleSubmit=()=>{                    
                         this.props.doLoginAction(this.state.userDetails)                                                
                    }

                    render(){
                      if(this.props.isLoggedIn) {
                        return this.props.isLoggedIn?<Redirect to="/app"/>:null
                      }

                    const { classes } = this.props;
                        return (
                          <main className={classes.main}>

                            <CssBaseline />
                            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                            <Typography className={this.state.errMsg===true?classes.showErr:classes.hideErr}> Invalid Credentials</Typography>                   
                              <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                  <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
                                  <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus onChange={(e)=>this.handleInput('email',e.target.value)} />
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                  <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                                  <Input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password"  onChange={(e)=>this.handleInput('password',e.target.value)} />
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormControlLabel
                                  control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                                  label="Remember me"
                                />
                                <Button
                                  type="submit"
                                  fullWidth
                                  variant="contained"
                                  className={classes.submit}
                                >
                                  Sign in
                                </Button>
                              </form>
                            </Paper>
                          </main>
                        );
                    }
                  }

                  SignInMain.propTypes = {
                    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
                  };

                  const SignIn=connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SignInMain)

                  export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(SignIn));
```

requireAuth.js

```
                import React from 'react';
                import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

                export default function requireAuth(Component){
                        class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component{
                            componentDidMount(){
                                console.log(Component)
                                this.checkAuth()
                            }

                            checkAuth=()=>{                                   
                                if(!this.props.isLoggedIn){
                                    const location=this.props.location;
                                    const redirect=location.pathname+location.search;
                                    this.props.router.push(`/?redirect=${redirect}`);
                                }
                            }

                            render(){                                   
                                return this.props.isLoggedIn
                                ?<Component {...this.props}/>
                                :null;
                            }
                        }
                    return withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);    
                }
```

console log

```
                action LOGIN_ACTION @ 14:08:55.700

                prev state {signInReducer: {…}}

                action     {type: "LOGIN_ACTION", payload: {…}}

                next state {signInReducer: {…}}

                {email: "qsds@sdfs.com", password: "sdfsdfsdf"}


                http://localhost:3000/user

                 {status: "200", isLoggedIn: true, msg: "successfully LoggedIn"}

                 {status: "200", isLoggedIn: true, msg: "successfully LoggedIn"}

                 {signInReducer: {…}}
                signInReducer: {isLoggedIn: true}
                __proto__: Object
                 action LOGIN_SUCCESS @ 08:42:33.989
                prev state {signInReducer: {…}}
                action     {type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: {…}, @@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true}payload: {status: "200", isLoggedIn: true, msg: "successfully LoggedIn"}type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS"@@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true__proto__: Object
                error      Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Please lemme know  I'm doing the right way where I'm going wrong I know I'm doing wrong then redirecting in render is causing the issue nor is it going to that state . Any help is appreciated.

I get the following error if I use push or redirect in  render function of signIn component I got the following error

Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Issue faced

1.When localhost:3000 then it calls sign in which correct but on success doesnt redirect to the specified page

2. When localhost:3000/app using HOC requireAuth calls sigin form which is correct but RequireAuth render is not called even after successfull login so that the we enter the component

Can anyone Please Please lemme know where I'm going wrong?
Please help

Comment: try adding  `event.preventDefault()` method to  `handleSubmit`

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty now I see the data in the reducer. but its not redireting to app page when isLoggedIn true. requireAuth Im passing the component to I think i'm missing onto something I cant figureout

Comment: can you update the question with `doLoginAction` code

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty Please check have update

Comment: you need to explictly redirect to another page after login, Are you doing that?

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty I've updated the signIn handle submit . is it there we need to exlicitly redirect ?

Comment: you shouldnot place that in the handle submit you need to place it in render, And it will be good if you redirect from reducer itself

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty but reducers are pure functions how can we redirect from their?

Comment: you can send history object to reducer as a perameter

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty Can u please send is a link how do we do that? Is that a good practise?

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty I get eror please check the updated code

Comment: Have you tried redirecting from render method of Signin.js

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty I got that error please check I have update the code

Comment: can you create a codepen or git repo of your code??

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty please check the update sigin.js code